# Highgraphs dynamically changing type

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying to change my Highcharts graph type triggered by a button action.

i.e.

```
customButton: {
    text: 'Graph Type',
    menuItems: [{
        text: 'Line',
        onclick: function() {
            chartType.chart.type = 'spline';
            $('#container').highcharts(chartType);
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Column',
        onclick: function() {
            chartType.chart.type = 'column';
            $('#container').highcharts(chartType);
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Scatter',
        onclick: function() {
            chartType.chart.type = 'scatter';
            $('#container').highcharts(chartType);
        }                                    
    }]
}
```

Changing the graphs worked like a charm but once I do that it breaks the zoom-in feature.
I receive 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'inClass' of undefined' for the mouseleave event.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems those navigation buttons don't like being re-initialized from inside their own callback.

I would avoid re-inited the whole chart and just modify the series inside the callback:

```
{
    text: 'Column',
    onclick: function() {
        Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update({
            type: 'column'
        });
    }
 }
```

This will not break the zoom.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxWE2/1/).

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update()